# My erlang code not printing as expected

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

```
**
-module(shubham).

-export([call/0, hi/0, guy/0]).


call() ->   hi().

hi() -> guy();

hi() -> io: fwrite("This is hi \n").

guy() -> io:fwrite("This is A guy\n").**
```

It should print "This is A guy" and then " This is hi" but only prints guy()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `,` instead of `;` after the fourth line and remove `hi() ->` like below:

```
 -module(shubham).
 -export([call/0, hi/0, guy/0]).
 call() -> hi().
 hi() -> guy(),
 io:fwrite("This is hi \n").
 guy() -> io:fwrite("This is A guy\n").
```